# How to add row in table only if that row is not present using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a table in database which has following structure(data) :

```
+--------------------------+
      Organization
+--------------------------+
    org_id | name
---------------------------
   1       | IBM
---------------------------
   2       | Google
---------------------------
   3       | Yahoo
+--------------------------+
```

In the above table, org_id is the primary key. I want to insert new row in this table only new organization name is found.

Other tables which are supposed to use this table are as follows :

```
+--------------------------+
      Project
+--------------------------+
 project_id| description
---------------------------
   1       | foo
---------------------------
   2       | bar...
---------------------------
   3       | xyz
+--------------------------+
```

and the table which connects project and Organization table is as follows :

```
+--------------------------+
      Project_Client
+--------------------------+
pc_id | project_id | org_id
---------------------------
   1  | 1          | 1
---------------------------
   2  | 1          | 3
---------------------------
   3  | 2          | 2
+--------------------------+
```

I want to implement something like this using hibernate :

Each project has its description and a list of client names. Client name is nothing but organization name. So to avoid duplicate data I have created table named `Organization`.

While inserting project information in database, if any client name already exist in `Organization` table then `org_id` of that client name should be used while inserting row in `Project_Client` table. If client name is not present in `Organization` table then new row should get added in `Organization` table and then corresponding `org_id` should be used in `Project_Client` table.

Can we implement something like this using hibernate?

> EDIT #1

Earlier I had classes as follows :

```
class Project {
    int projectID;
    String description;
    set<String> clients;
    set<String> employers;
    set<String> technologies;
}
```

As you can see, each project will have one or more client, employer and technology also. I want to avoid duplication of organization name and technology name across multiple projects. For example, if for some project client is XYZ and for other project also client is XYZ then I just want to refer to same `org_id` in `organization` table instead of creating separate rows for same organization.

I was hoping that hibernate will allow me to achieve this easily but I was not able to achieve it using  or with  and  . So I changed my class structure as follows :

```
class Entity {
    int id;
    String name;
}

class Client extends Entity {
    // nothing special here
}

class Employer extends Entity {
    // nothing special here
}

class Technology extends Entity {
    // nothing special here
}

class Project {
    int projectID;
    List<Client> clients;
    List<Employer> employers;
    List<Technology> technologies;
}
```

I have created seperate mapping files for `Client`,`Employer` and `Technology` classes. Even this also has not helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [one-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) `Project` and `Organization` should ideally solve the issue.
Whenever you try adding organization to a project

The classes can be defined as :

```
public class Project {
    private int projectId;
    private Set<Organization> clients;

    public void addClient(Organization org){
        if(clients==null){
            clients=new HashSet<Organization>();
        }
        org.setProject(this);
        clients.add(org);
    }
}

public class Organization{
    private int organizationId;
    private Project project;       //if bi-directional relation is required.
}
```

Thus

1. `Project` will map to table Project
2. `Organization` will map to table
3. The relation can be mapped to `Project_Client`

the relation can be mapping as :

**Note :** `many-to-many` used with `unique=true` as one-to-many is not aware of join table

```
<class name="Project" table="Project">
  <!-- just showing the relational mapping here , you can figure out the rest -->
  <set name="clients" table="Project_Client">
   <key column="project_id"/>
   <many-to-many class="Organization" unique="true" column="org_id"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

Rest of the classes are mapped normally

[Cascading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades) can be considered if you dont want to handle the life cycle of `Organization`.

To add an Organization to a Project

- Query to find Organization with the name.
- if Organization found the Organization is added to the Project using the helper function `addClient()`
- if no Organization found do, create one and then use `addClient()`

Hope this helps.

### After Edit to the question:

The question was edited to support multiple `Set` of String [Client, Technology]
Since your problem statement requires that the `Employer` , `Technology` and `Client` be independent Entities (that is they should be shared between different `Projects`) you would need to define them as separate Entity. In the question Technology extends Entity just due to the fact that it has similar properties ( this might not be the case in future).

Hence I suggest that each of Organization, Employer and Technology be mapped to separate table. As these will have many-to-many relationship with Project there will be a separate relational table for each. Following is the updated table , class and hibernate mapping:

### Table Structure

```
Project (projectId, ...)
Organization (orgId,name)
Technology (technologyId,name)
Employer(employerId,name)
```

corresponding relational tables as

```
project_organization (projectid,orgid)
project_employer (projectid,employerid)
project_tecnology(projectid,technologyid)
```

### Class Structure

```
public class Project{
 private int projectId;
 private Set<Organization> clients;
 private Set<Employer> employer;
 private Set<Technology> technology;

  //..appropriate getter/setter and helper functions [like the one shown above]
}
```

### Hibernate Mapping

```
<class name="Project" table="Project">
  <!-- just showing the relational mapping here , you can figure out the rest -->
  <set name="clients" table="Project_Client">
   <key column="projectid"/>
   <many-to-many class="Organization" unique="true" column="org_id"/>
  </set>
  <set name="technology" table="Project_Technology">
   <key column="projectid"/>
   <many-to-many class="Technology" unique="true" column="technologyid"/>
  </set>
  <set name="employer" table="Project_Employer">
   <key column="projectid"/>
   <many-to-many class="Employer" unique="true" column="employerid"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your valuable answer. I have couple of queries about the last part. How to query to find organization with given name? Do I need to write SQL? and like set of clients, if I have a set of employers also and set of technologies also then do I need to create separate classes for employer and technology also? For me, employer,technology and clients are just a set/list of strings.

Comment: You can use HQL/Criteria to fetch the required Organization object. if the object is not found as i mentioned you need to create one and save it using SaveOrUpdate() before adding it to the List of Clients on Project. I did not get the second part of your comment, Could be more specific

Comment: Its difficult to express everything as a comment, so I am editing my question. I hope it will make picture clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified my classes and database as per your suggestions. Hibernate has created tables automatically just as I wanted it to. Now only problem remaining is, how to check whether organization name already exist in database or not? Because now hibernate is throwing following exception :

ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry 'lloyds tsb' for key 'CLIENT_NAME'
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [Client]

I am sorry if I am asking too many questions.

Comment: :D I imagine that this is the your are new at Hibernate and you will get many doubts at this stage.I used to go through the JBoss Hibernate documentation which has ample examples for everything that can be done using Hibernate. I think you might not be saving the client object using saveorupdate() before adding it to a collection/association with Project. Any collection objects need to saved first before they can be added to a collection [IF CASCADING IS IGNORED]. Have a good look at the documentation for one-to-many association handling in Hibernate and ask more questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot frictionlesspulley. I will definitely go through hibernate documentation. I forgot the rule of RTFAPI :)

Comment: The important part of the question is how to *find or create* the Organization.. This answer hasn't really dealt with that key element of the question.

Comment: @ThomasW that the answer was accept implies that it WAS answered

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the complete implementation, but I hope this can be achieved if you follow the below steps.

**Step 1 :** Create Beans corresponding to table `Project_Client` and `Organization`.

**Step 2 :** Have a field `organizationId` in `Project_Client` bean.

**Step 3 :** When you prepare the `Project_Client` object for insertion, fire a query to find if the `Organization` in already present get the `organizationId` from the DB and set it to `Project_Client`

**Step 4 :**  Else create a new entry in the DB for `Organization` and set its 'id' as 'organizationId' in the `Project_Client` bean.

**Step 5 :** Save the `Project_Client` bean to the DB.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but how to perform all those steps using hibernate? Also, project_client is just a link table to connect project with its clients. I don't want to create separate class for project_client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would do something like so:

```
public Organization getOrCreateOrganization(String name) {
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Organization.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    Organization result = (Organization)crit.uniqueResult();
    if (result == null) {
        result = new Organization();
        result.setName(name);
        session.save(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I call such methods 'representXyz', and *represent* is defined as either getting or creating if none exists. In your case, 'representOrganization' -- which should be either a static, or in a Service/Model class.